# Why doesn't my server print text (or do anything) in my Server/Client chat?

Tags: java, javafx, server, client

I have to create Java program with GUI that simply is a text chat between a server and a client. I have referred to my professor's Powerpoint presentation and copied example code of a server and client program that where the client types a circle radius, and the server automatically calculates and returns the client the circle area (The example code did not have a textfield for input). I have changed up the example code into code where the server and client can chat with each other in text. My Client class works and I did not have to change anything in the Client class except that the text inputted stays as a string and not a double.

I tested my server. Why does my server freeze when I hit enter after inputting simple text?

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class Server extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Text area for displaying contents
    BorderPane paneForTextField = new BorderPane();
    paneForTextField.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
    paneForTextField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
    paneForTextField.setLeft(new Label("Type here: "));
    TextField tf = new TextField();

    tf.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    paneForTextField.setCenter(tf);
    BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(ta));
    mainPane.setTop(paneForTextField);


    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

     try {

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
      // Socket socket = new Socket("130.254.204.36", 8000);
      // Socket socket = new Socket("drake.Armstrong.edu", 8000);

      // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
      DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

      // Create an output stream to send data to the server
      DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        // Get the radius from the text field
        String serverText = tf.getText();

        // Send the radius to the server
        outputToClient.writeBytes(serverText);
        outputToClient.flush();

        // Get area from the server
        String clientText = inputFromClient.readLine();

        // Display to the text area
        ta.appendText("Client: " + clientText + "\n");
        ta.appendText("Server: " + serverText + '\n');
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString() + '\n');
      }



    tf.setOnAction(e -> {
            new Thread( () -> {




      try {
        // Create a server socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Platform.runLater(() ->
        ta.appendText("Server is working" + '\n'));

        // Listen for a connection request
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        // Create data input and output streams
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
          socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(
          socket.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
          // Receive radius from the client
          String clientText = inputFromClient.readLine();
          String serverText = tf.getText();


          // Compute area

          // Send area back to the client
          outputToClient.writeBytes("Server: " + serverText);

          Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ta.appendText("Client: " + clientText + '\n');
            ta.appendText("Server: " + serverText + '\n'); 
          });
        }
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

    }).start();

    });







  }



  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Client extends Application {
  // IO streams
  DataOutputStream toServer = null;
  DataInputStream fromServer = null;

  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // Panel p to hold the label and text field
    BorderPane paneForTextField = new BorderPane();
    paneForTextField.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
    paneForTextField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
    paneForTextField.setLeft(new Label("Type here: "));

    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    paneForTextField.setCenter(tf);

    BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
    // Text area to display contents
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();
    mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(ta));
    mainPane.setTop(paneForTextField);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Client"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    tf.setOnAction(e -> {
      try {
        // Get the text from the text field
        String clientText = tf.getText();

        // Send the text to the server
        toServer.writeBytes(clientText);
        toServer.flush();

        // Get text from the server
        String serverText = fromServer.readLine();

        // Display to the text area
        ta.appendText("Client: " + clientText + "\n");
        ta.appendText("Server: " + serverText + '\n');
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }
    });

    try {
      // Create a socket to connect to the server
      Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);


      // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
      fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

      // Create an output stream to send data to the server
      toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ta.appendText(ex.toString() + '\n');
    }
  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question title suggests that you are tying up your GUI's main thread. Use a background thread for long-running code.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter When you mean "background" thread, where should I move my Thread?

Comment: Ah, I see, you are creating a new thread, but it doesn't look to be in the right place. It likely will need to be within the on action block, not surrounding it, but again, I'm not JavaFX expert.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Still doesn't work I did what you said

Comment: The threading should not go where you send information out from the text field to the socket, but rather just the data coming in from the InputStream into the GUI. Again, search for similar questions as I'm sure that they're out there.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Actually I fixed the code so it doesn't freeze anymore. I have to edit my question. My Server is not printing the text I type into the TextArea where the chat log is.

Comment: Please feel free to edit/improve your question when you see fit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did update it about a few minutes ago, but here I go again, I am updating it again, because I changed my code where I see all kinds of green text at the bottom of JGrasp, so I assume the Server is doing something. Now I just need to get the text printed.

Comment: You still don't appear to be doing what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581859/why-doesnt-my-server-print-text-or-do-anything-in-my-server-client-chat#comment82121870_47581859).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll redo my code again. I will start off from the example code all over again and then I will share whatever code I have.